# Reactive Loop in R Shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I've been stuck on this problem for hours.  I tried to create a simpler version of my actual use case to see if I can debug the problem but still having trouble.

My shiny app is below.  It takes an input from user, runs it through some calculations until it meets a threshold, then collects the value in a list.  It does this for several iterations (10 here in the example), then plots a histogram of these values.

The specific error I'm getting says

```
Warning: Error in : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

I think that my error is related to the way I'm using `x.new`, but I can't figure out how to code it differently.

```
# install.packages('shiny')
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Title Here'),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput('x.qty', 'Pick a number', 3, 1, 10)),
  mainPanel(plotOutput('valueplot'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- reactive({
    x.list <- list()
    for (i in 1:10){
      x.new <- reactive({input$x.qty * sample(1:10, 1)})
      repeat{
        if (x.new() > 20){
          x.list <- c(x.list, x.new())
          results <- x.list
          break
        } # end if loop
        x.new <- reactive({x.new() * sample(1:10, 1)})
      } # end repeat
    } # end for loop
    results
  })
  output$valueplot <- renderPlot({hist(as.numeric(results()))})
}  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The basic issue here is that `x.new()` is a reactive that is defined more than once, so shiny does not know what it should be. Can you re-write this to avoid that, perhaps by using a reactive variable or just two different names?

Comment: The problem is I need it to reference itself.  So, user chooses 3 for `x.qty`...`x.new` multiplies 3 by a random number...say 2 for example.  That's not greater than 20, so I want the new value of `x.new` to be 6 and get multiplied by another number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to modify your server function in the following way:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- reactive({
    x.list <- list()
    for (i in 1:10){
      x.new <- input$x.qty * sample(1:10, 1)
      repeat{
        if (x.new > 20){
          x.list <- c(x.list, x.new)
          results <- x.list
          break
        } # end if loop
        x.new <- x.new * sample(1:10, 1)
      } # end repeat
    } # end for loop
    results
  })
  output$valueplot <- renderPlot({hist(as.numeric(results()))})
}
```

This way you avoid the infinite recursion provoked by

```
x.new <- reactive({x.new() * sample(1:10, 1)})
```

Comment: This has the desired output, and looks a little cleaner than the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as you want? Each `for` loop iteration, `x.new` is calculated using `x.qty` then in the `repeat` loop `x.new` recursively multiplies itself by a random number until it is greater than 20.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(headerPanel('Title Here'),
                sidebarPanel(numericInput('x.qty', 'Pick a number', 3, 1, 10)),
                mainPanel(plotOutput('valueplot')))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  x.new <- function(x) {
    x * sample(1:10, 1)
  }

  results <- reactive({
    x.list <- list()
    for (i in 1:10) {
      x.new_draw <- x.new(input$x.qty)
      repeat {
        if (x.new_draw > 20) {
          x.list <- c(x.list, x.new_draw)
          break
        } # end if loop
        x.new_draw <- x.new(x.new_draw)
      } # end repeat
    } # end for loop
    x.list
  })
  output$valueplot <- renderPlot({
    hist(as.numeric(results()))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes!  This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Do you mind adding a brief explanation of why this works?

Comment: Hi sorry late reply. The `x.new` function simply multiplied a number by a random number so didn't need to be reactive. I've used it as a function just by habit - in case you want to change the random number generation you only need to change it in one spot compared to the other answer. Also you are already accumulating results in `x.list` so there is no need to then copy this into `results` as this vector could be confused with the reactive function also named `results`, even though they are different. You can just return `x.list` at the end